# Is it possible to draw any arbitary degree Eliptical Arc with SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I am trying to smoothen the transition from a diagonal line to a horizontal line by using arcs of circles that I calculate with a little calculus. The problem I am running into is that it seems as though I can't get the arcs to be positioned correctly.

For example: [jsfiddle.net/5Wa9e/2](http://jsfiddle.net/5Wa9e/2)

It might just be a problem with my calculations but from "inspection" it seems as though I have the right circles. I want the red points on the right to always be at the bottom of the circle at the point where the tangent is horizontal.

I am using: `A#{radius},#{radius} 0 0 0 #{curveEndX},#{curveEndY}"` to define the arc. Am I missing something?

--edit--
It was just my math. Turns out the arcs I see are just fallback mechanisms for when the SVG renderer can't find a circle matching my constraints.

--edit--
end result: [jsfiddle.net/5Wa9e/2](http://jsfiddle.net/5Wa9e/2)

Comment: I thought this was a fun question and the answer not obvious except that using a circle to connect would be least-ideal in most situations (a non-circle ellipse being better), so I did a quick lookup and the idea (though it doesn't really present the math) shown here http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Line-Design is quite intriguing for a smooth connection... projecting the lines outward to intersection and dividing up the distance between their start points and the intersection into even distances, then drawing short lines connecting them together.

Comment: That's really cool!
I ended up solving my issue. There was a small problem with my math. I also think there are some rounding errors but this is what I ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/yKvh7/1/

Comment: Found my magic number and did some rounding compensation and it works perfectly now tested at a bunch of different sizes! :) http://jsfiddle.net/yKvh7/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Wa9e/2/

Comment: Your question was about arbitry lines meeting at a curved point.  While your fiddle IS QUITE IMPRESSIVE... what would you do for angles whose acute value was < 90? = 90? < 180? -- I'm not saying I have the solution, but prompting discussion (which I'm not sure is appropriate for stackoverlow, but, again, I thought this was a fun question.)

Comment: There are always 2 circles so you can just use the other circle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/5Wa9e/3/